# Change the state of an element to show an array of Components after API call

Tags: arrays, reactjs, next.js, state

I recently picked up Next.js, and before going into any backend stuff, I took a look over React and many things needed of it.

In short, I have built a form, which will take the input of the user, use it in the API and return me a JSON Object, that will edit some of my Components that I will later show. So I used state.
I use an auxiliary variable to set up a boolean state, that will be set to true once my Components will be edited. Now, my Components are stored in an array, that I will show after it got edited later. Here's the code

to avoid confusion, showResults is another state that works as intended. my issues are with showMatch and setShowMatch

```
function Form() {

    // adding state to the HeadingText Component to hide it once the user presses the Search button
    const [showResults, setShowResults] = React.useState(true)
    
    // adding state to the auxiliary variable to show my array later after edit
    const [showMatch, setShowMatch] = React.useState(false)

    let matches = []

    // adding the form handling section, with async event to query the API
    const registerUser = async event => {
        event.preventDefault() // don't redirect the page

        // hiding the Component HeadingText, so we show only the data of the games
        setShowResults(false)

        // calling the API in api/register, passing the link of the game or anything we would like to pass
        const res = await fetch('/api/register', {
            body: JSON.stringify({ matchLink: event.target.matchLink.value }),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            method: 'POST'
        })

        //querying the real API, printing out the result
        const result = await res.json()
        console.log(result)

        //preparing my array of components
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            matches.push(<Match
                title = { `game   ${i} `}
                nOfGame = {i}
                game = {result.rounds[i]}
            />);
        }

        setShowMatch(true);
        console.log('I have changed the state, I check if it is true or false, if true: print my array, else: print null')
        console.log(showMatch ? matches : null)
        console.log('I will print my array to double check it\'s value')
        console.log(matches)
    }

    return (
        <>
            { /* Showing or not the component Heading Text */ }
            { showResults ? <HeadingText /> : null }
            
            <div className="form-container">
                <form onSubmit={registerUser}>
                    <input type="text" name="matchLink" id="textFiledId" placeholder="insert a demo" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" name="subDemo" />
                </form>
            </div>

            { /* Showing or not the component of the match */ }
            <div className="match-holder">
                { showMatch ? matches : null } 
            </div>

            <p>{matches.length}</p> {/* This should be 0 */ }
        </>
    )
}

export default Form
```

I am not understanding how I may be able to show my array of Components, as this message in the console https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4pap.jpg is telling me my array is full of components. I am 100% sure I am missing something but after some time running over the state doc of React, I couldn't find an example that helped

(A question I have looked at [Correct modification of state arrays in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-react-js))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a local non-state variable `matches` in your component which means no matter how you update it in `registerUser` function, everytime there is a state variable update, it will trigger a re-render and `matches` will again be initialized to `[]`

What you need is a new state variable initialized as `[]`, and you can set it in your `registerUser` function. It will retain its value upon re-renders unless explicitly changed.

Storing components in state has performance implications, rather store the required `props` for mentioned array of components as array of objects in state and render your component using it.

Here is a sample implementation

```
function Form() {

    // adding state to the HeadingText Component to hide it once the user presses the Search button
    const [showResults, setShowResults] = React.useState(true)

    const [matches, setMatches] = React.useState([])

    // adding the form handling section, with async event to query the API
    const registerUser = async event => {
        event.preventDefault() // don't redirect the page

        // hiding the Component HeadingText, so we show only the data of the games
        setShowResults(false)

        // calling the API in api/register, passing the link of the game or anything we would like to pass
        const res = await fetch('/api/register', {
            body: JSON.stringify({ matchLink: event.target.matchLink.value }),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            method: 'POST'
        })

        //querying the real API, printing out the result
        const result = await res.json()
        console.log(result)

        let nmatch = []

        //preparing my array of components
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            nmatch.push({
                title: `game   ${i} `
                nOfGame: i
                game: result.rounds[i]
            });
        }
        setMatches(nmatch)
    }

    return (
        <>
            { /* Showing or not the component Heading Text */ }
            { showResults ? <HeadingText /> : null }

            <div className="form-container">
                <form onSubmit={registerUser}>
                    <input type="text" name="matchLink" id="textFiledId" placeholder="insert a demo" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" name="subDemo" />
                </form>
            </div>

            { /* Showing or not the component of the match */ }
            <div className="match-holder">
                { matches.length > 0 && (
                  matches.map(m => (
                    <Match
                      key={m.title}
                      {...m}
                    />
                  ))
                )}
            </div>
            <p>{matches.length}</p> {/* This should be 0 */ }
        </>
    )
}

export default Form
```

Comment: So here the code sets up an empty array as a state, that I will change after my API call in the registerUser function. Once it's done and I have my data, it will change the state of the array and re-render it? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. This is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your example and explanation, this helped me with the issue and corrected my code, glad you helped me